# knitr inline comments for arguments

Tags: r, format, comments, knitr

When knitting this code snippet:

```
<<test>>=
f <- function( 
    x, #arg description
    y) x*y
f(3, 4) 
@
```

I get the error:

```
label: test
Warning in block_exec(params) :
  failed to tidy R code in chunk <test>
reason: Error in base::parse(text = code, srcfile = NULL) : 
  2:5: unexpected SPECIAL
1: f <- function (
2: x , %InLiNe_IdEnTiFiEr%
       ^
```

The problem is linked to `tidy.source()`, which is unable to format the given block.

Commenting function arguments in place is a very common and often suggested practice. I think this behaviour might be not by design, since in the past it was possible to use these type of comments.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you get a warning - not an error.  It still should produce a document it just won't be tidied.  It doesn't know how to tidy that and I don't think that's a great way to format your code so I'm ok with not being able to tidy that code.

If you want to eliminate the warning you can do this

```
<<test, tidy=FALSE>>=
f <- function( 
    x, #arg description
    y) x*y
f(3, 4) 
@
```

You won't have your code tidied for you but you won't get the warning.

Answer (score 2):

Comments cannot be retained within an incomplete expression.

See section 6  of https://github.com/yihui/formatR/wiki.

This has been noted as (closed) issue [#15](https://github.com/yihui/formatR/issues/15)  by the package author. (Using`roxygen2` or similar is a "better" alternative for documenting functions).

Comment: breaking `1+2` (as on [formatR/wiki](https://github.com/yihui/formatR/wiki) is different from breaking `function(x,y)`. Anyway it should work by adding `\n` at  the end of inline comments, as written here [github.com/yihui/formatR/commit/6f70360f359](https://github.com/yihui/formatR/commit/6f70360f359). But it doesn't work for me.